# IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve directory ${contextRoot}

Tags: intellij-idea, code-inspection

*It is a minor inconvenience.* IntelliJ IDEA inspection reports unresovable file path when it actually exists. For example on this line in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${contextRoot}/app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

inspection says: `Cannot resolve directory ${contextRoot}`.

How can I fix the inspection without disabling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit inspection settings as indicated in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-inspection-settings.html), but i'm not sure you can do anything other than just disable it.